# Could the sequence A287326 be generalized in order to receive expansion of natural power n>3?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics

The sequence https://oeis.org/A287326 - is Binomial distributed triangular array, that shows us necessary items to expand perfect cube $n^3$. Summation of $n$-th row of Triangle A287326 from $0$ to $n-1$ returns $n^3$. But is it exist simillar patterns in order to receive expansion of power $n>3$, where $n$ - positive integer?

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    &    &    &    &    &  1\\
&    &    &    &  1 &   &  1\\
&    &    &  1 &    &  7&    &  1\\
&    &  1 &    &  13&   &  13&    &  1\\
&  1 &    &  19&    & 25&    &  19&    &  1\\
    \end{matrix}
$$
Figure 1. Triangle A287326.

It derived by means of identity 
$$
x^3=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{x-1}3!\cdot mx-3!\cdot m^2+1
$$

For detailed info on derivation, please, reffer to links below. Thank you !

- Derivation of A287326: https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/Overview_of_preprint_1603.02468.pdf
- Dedicated preprint: https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/series_representation_of_power_function.pdf

Comment: If you want your post to look less like spam and more like an inquiry, post only two links: one to your repository (and put your table of contents behind the link), and the other to some work done independently by a different researcher that you do not find on OEIS.  Gerhard "We Must Keep Up Appearances" Paseman, 2018.02.19.

Comment: Dear Gerhard, thank you for your reply, excessed links removed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which generalization of this you might be interested in.  But you might note that

$$ x^k = \sum_{m=0}^{x-1} ((m+1)^k - m^k) = \sum_{m=0}^{x-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {k \choose j} m^j $$

Comment: Dear Robert, this fact is noticed and could be found at second link, on the page 2, lemma (1.4)

Comment: We looking not for generalization by means of finite differences (which for sure already known), we looking for generaliation of above triangle for powers $m>3$